Проблема с tooltip из react-bootstrap
Если кто работал с тултипом из react-bootstrap, помогите, пожалуйста: у меня есть таблица с ячейками (каждая ячейка закрашивается цветом). И при наведении на ячейку появляется тултип с определенной информацией. Проблема в том, что при наведении на ячейку "скачет" страница (как будто ререндеринг, но его нет), и тултип для каждой ячейки почему-то рисуется три раза (проверила по console.log).

На первом скриншоте сама ячейка таблицы.

На втором скриншоте функция, рисующая тултип.

как задать хороший вопрос. начните с заголовка.
